# 'ion-avatar' is not a known element Error message

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Inherited the following Ionic Angular code for a project. My `user-photo.component.html` looks like:

```
<ion-avatar *ngIf="userObject.userPhoto && userObject.userPhoto !== ''">
    <img [src]="userObject.userPhoto" />
</ion-avatar>
```

My Component `user-photo.component.ts` looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-photo',
  templateUrl: './user-photo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-photo.component.scss'],
})
export class UserPhotoComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() userObject: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Getting the following errors in VS Code and while trying to build:

```
[ng] Error: src/app/shared/components/user-photo/user-photo.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'ion-avatar' is not a known element:
```

```
[ng] 1. If 'ion-avatar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

```
[ng] 2. If 'ion-avatar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

ion-avatar is part of the media package in the Ionic Framework: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/avatar

Don't understand why it is not resolving the `'ion-avatar'` since I'm importing `'Component'`.

One other thing. This is a 'shared' module this looks like this in `shared.module.ts:`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { UserPhotoComponent } from './components/user-photo/user-photo.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [UserPhotoComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
    ], 
    exports: [
        UserPhotoComponent
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Ensured that `'ion-avatar'` is properly imported from `'Component'`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ion-avatar` component forms part of the `IonicModule`.

You need to import it underneath `CommonModule`:

```
...
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule
    ],
...
```